# DateTime calculation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to create a countdown based on the lottery drawing times.

If the current date time is greater than the current weeks Wednesday then we display the current week Saturday's date time.

If the current date time is greater than the current weeks Saturday then we display the next Wednesday date time.

I don't want it to display for the last hour of that day.

I'm using moment and moment timezone.

```
var current = new Date(moment().tz('America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
var wednesday = new Date().wednesday(); //if we are past the current Wednesday, it returns next weeks Wednesday
var wednesdayLimit = new Date(wednesday.getFullYear(), wednesday.getMonth(), wednesday.getDate(), 22, 59, 00);
var saturday = new Date().saturday();
var saturdayLimit = new Date(saturday.getFullYear(), saturday.getMonth(), saturday.getDate(), 22, 59, 00);

if (current > wednesdayLimit && current < saturdayLimit)
{
    var temp = moment(saturdayLimit).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    $('.countdown').data('date', temp);
    $(".countdown").TimeCircles();
}
else if (current > saturdayLimit && current < wenesdayLimit)
{
    var temp = moment(wednesdayLimit).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    $('.countdown').data('date', temp);
    $(".countdown").TimeCircles();
}
```

Maybe i'm over complicating it.

https://jsfiddle.net/1bLj4m2t/11/

***UPDATE***

Sorry, let me try to clarify. The countdown should not display between 22:59:01 - 23:59:59 on Wed or Sat. The last 1 hour and 1 minute of the day. This is why I created the *Limit vars and adjusted them to 22:59:00.

So to display the wednesdayLimit the current date time would need to be between 
`Thursdays 00:00:00 and Saturday 22:59:00`

now to display saturdayLimit the current date time would need to be between
`Sunday 00:00:00 and Wednesday 22:59:00`

***UPDATE 2***
https://jsfiddle.net/1bLj4m2t/11/

Currently working but might be a cleaner/better way to do this?

Comment: `else if (current > saturdayLimit && current > saturdayLimit)` same condition twice?

Comment: sorry updated that line.

Comment: you should make fiddle for this. currently what values you are getting?

Comment: working fiddle added

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to check which date is near to today? Is it Wednesday or Saturday? In other words check if Saturday is greater than Wednesday or vice versa. (Or find out which is minimum of the two)

Here is updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/1bLj4m2t/6/

```
var current = new Date(moment().tz('America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
var wednesday = new Date().wednesday();
var saturday = new Date().saturday();

$('.current').html(current);
$('.wednesday').html(wednesday);
$('.saturday').html(saturday);

var currentWeekday = moment(current).weekday();
var wednesdayWeekday = moment(wednesday).weekday();
var saturdayWeekday = moment(saturday).weekday();
var temp = (currentWeekday == wednesdayWeekday || currentWeekday == saturdayWeekday)? current :  Math.min(wednesday, saturday);

$('.countdown').html(moment(temp).fromNow()); // use appropriate time of temp date
```

**UPDATE**: Added logic to check if current day is wednesday / saturday.

**UPDATE 2**: I've checked your updated fiddle and noticed that you are using momentjs & datejs. Do you really need 2 libraries? I'll stick to momentjs.

Looking at different values of `current` and the expected result that you have mentioned in your fiddle v11 I've updated my code @ https://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/1bLj4m2t/14/

```
//var current = moment('2016/01/17 08:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Wed
//var current = moment('2016/01/20 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Wed
//var current = moment('2016/01/20 22:59:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Wed last hour
//var current = moment('2016/01/20 23:59:59', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Wed last hour
//var current = moment('2016/01/21 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Sat
//var current = moment('2016/01/23 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Sat
var current = moment('2016/01/23 22:59:01', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'); //display Sat last hour

var wednesday = moment(current).day(3); // sun=0 ... sat=6
var saturday = moment(current).day(6);

var currentWeekday = current.weekday();
var wednesdayWeekday = wednesday.weekday();
//var saturdayWeekday = moment(saturday).weekday();
var showWednesday = currentWeekday <= wednesdayWeekday;
var temp = showWednesday? wednesday : saturday;

temp = temp.hours(23).minutes(59).seconds(59).milliseconds(999);

$('.current').html(current.toDate());
$('.wednesday').html(wednesday.toDate());
$('.saturday').html(saturday.toDate());

$('.countdown').html((showWednesday? "Wed" : "Sat") +
  (temp.diff(current, "minutes") <= 60 ? " last hour" : ""));
```

*Note*:

1. `.day()` function returns the day of current week (unlike `wednesday()`/`saturday()` that you are using). This allows me to simply compare weekday of `current` with weekday of `wednesday` to decide whether to use `wednesday` or `saturday` for further calculations
2. To check if its the last hour of temp(wednesday/saturday), you just check the difference is <= 60 minutes
3. I've used the date strings as you have used in your example and hence used the second param 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss' while calling moment(). Ref: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 to know recommended ways of using moment()
4. While displaying the date I've used `.toDate()` but you can use [`.format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: updated post, hope I was able to clarify it a little better.

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle. I got it to work but maybe you know a cleaner way/better way? https://jsfiddle.net/1bLj4m2t/9/

Comment: Its showing me "Current: Invalid Date" inside $('.current'). Is that the right version I'm looking at?

Comment: Actually I see this works correct in Chrome but IE 11, FireFox shows invalid.

Comment: fixed in https://jsfiddle.net/1bLj4m2t/11/ apparently I had to use `/` instead of `-` to work across browsers.